# i've got an error for B4a or Basic 4 android can someone help me to fix it PDFVIEWER

Tags: basic4android

```
** Activity (categories) Pause, UserClosed = false **
** Activity (books) Create, isFirst = true **
** Activity (books) Resume **
** Activity (books) Pause, UserClosed = false **
** Activity (pdfviewer) Create, isFirst = true **
pagecount:470
pc:470
** Activity (pdfviewer) Resume **
** Activity (pdfviewer) Pause, UserClosed = true **
** Activity (books) Resume **
** Activity (books) Pause, UserClosed = false **
** Activity (pdfviewer) Create, isFirst = false **
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 8065 (FinalizerDaemon)
Logger connected to:  OPPO CPH1613
--------- beginning of crash
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 20664 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 20895 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 21526 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 27897 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 29300 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 12649 (FinalizerDaemon)
--------- beginning of system
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 16740 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 22794 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 23064 (RendererWorkerT)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 23078 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 23208 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 29825 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 32069 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 32120 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 32163 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 32222 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 900 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 952 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 1548 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 1594 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 1638 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 1981 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 2427 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 2488 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 2893 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 2944 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 3452 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 3597 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 5299 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 5364 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 5847 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 5922 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 6067 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 6105 (FinalizerDaemon)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 7096 (FinalizerDaemon)
--------- beginning of main
** Activity (pdfviewer) Pause, UserClosed = true **
** Activity (books) Resume **
** Activity (books) Pause, UserClosed = false **
** Activity (pdfviewer) Create, isFirst = false **
pagecount:60
pc:60
** Activity (pdfviewer) Resume **
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 7134 (FinalizerDaemon)
** Activity (books) Create, isFirst = true **
** Activity (books) Resume **
** Activity (books) Pause, UserClosed = false **
** Activity (books) Resume **
** Activity (books) Pause, UserClosed = true **
** Activity (categories) Create, isFirst = true **
** Activity (categories) Resume **
** Activity (categories) Pause, UserClosed = false **
** Activity (books) Create, isFirst = false **
** Activity (books) Resume **
** Activity (books) Pause, UserClosed = false **
** Activity (pdfviewer) Create, isFirst = true **
pagecount:182
pc:182
** Activity (pdfviewer) Resume **
** Activity (pdfviewer) Pause, UserClosed = true **
** Activity (books) Resume **
** Activity (books) Pause, UserClosed = false **
** Activity (pdfviewer) Create, isFirst = false **
pagecount:76
pc:76
** Activity (pdfviewer) Resume **
** Activity (pdfviewer) Pause, UserClosed = true **
** Activity (books) Resume **
** Activity (books) Pause, UserClosed = true **
** Activity (categories) Resume **
** Activity (categories) Pause, UserClosed = false **
** Activity (books) Create, isFirst = false **
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 7200 (FinalizerDaemon)
** Activity (categories) Create, isFirst = true **
** Activity (categories) Resume **
** Activity (categories) Pause, UserClosed = true **
** Activity (home) Create, isFirst = true **
** Activity (home) Resume **
** Activity (home) Pause, UserClosed = true **
** Activity (categories) Create, isFirst = false **
** Activity (categories) Resume **
** Activity (categories) Pause, UserClosed = false **
** Activity (books) Create, isFirst = true **
** Activity (books) Resume **
** Activity (books) Pause, UserClosed = false **
** Activity (pdfviewer) Create, isFirst = true **
pagecount:470
pc:470
** Activity (pdfviewer) Resume **
** Activity (pdfviewer) Pause, UserClosed = true **
** Activity (books) Resume **
** Activity (books) Pause, UserClosed = false **
** Activity (pdfviewer) Create, isFirst = false **
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 8065 (FinalizerDaemon)
pagecount:60
pc:60
** Activity (pdfviewer) Resume **
** Activity (categories) Create, isFirst = true **
** Activity (categories) Resume **
```

Answer (score 0):

Use largeHeap in manfiest (of course it is suggest)

Also i suggest below link in B4a.com

https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/free-pdfviewer-by-icefairy333-reworked-by-donmanfred.66870/#content